# Design ideas for Skeptics

Tags: discussion, design

After 90 days in beta, Stack Exchange Inc. takes evaluates our site's performance. If they think we're ready for graduation because we meet [the right metrics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptics), then [we get out of beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/). When that happens, **[Jin](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/our-designer-in-residence-jin-yang/) will give our site its own unique look** rather than the current generic design that all beta sites have.

Jin's very talented. Here's some of his best work:

- [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)
- [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)
- [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/)

All sites share quite a bit of common elements so they feel like they're part of the Stack Exchange family, but the look of those elements can be modified to reflect the topic of the site.

Let's give Jin a hand and **start the brain storming *now*!**

Comment: Thank you for starting the design discussion Borror0! I look forward to the day I design for this site!

Comment: Is this site likely to graduate in the first place?

Comment: @Sejanus: So far, [we're looking really good](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptics). About a third of the way before the first evaluation, and we're close to excellent in all metrics. I suspect we'll be "ready" for launch by the end of April.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Since Atheism failed I had my doubts about skeptics too.

Comment: @Sejanus i think that you were skeptical about skeptics too ;)

Answer (score 8):

Since we now read every day a new posting about adding links to studies in our answers, the relevant **symbols** for the page are **books, libraries, papers** and the like.

Comment: I think making it look *too* Academic is a bad idea. So I would caution against too much use of these.

Comment: But if you encourage only academic answers, this would be consequent and attract just the right audience.

Comment: If there's a way to graphically represent **evidence** without making it look *too academic*, as @rjstelling puts it, I would support that.

Comment: @JasonPlank: Agreed!

Answer (score 3):

Let me chip with a couple of pence:

**Dark text on light background**

Besides that 2 ideas (links point to image examples):

1. Themed around famous skeptics: [Bertrand Russell](http://www.superhappiness.com/bertrand-russell.html), [Carl Sagan](http://www.phys.lsu.edu/students/brunner/images/sagan2.jpg), etc.
2. Themed around classic pseudoscience: [ESP](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_il5FBpex0Ys/TGz-05uQsmI/AAAAAAAAAGA/sMmbVOTaZNA/s400/2.png), aliens, [classic UFOs](http://img.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2007/07_02/ClassicUFOL_468x366.jpg), [egyptian symbols](http://thepyramidofpower.com/j/images/stories/hieroglyphics-table_small.jpg), etc.

Comment: No aliens. *Please.*

Comment: I thought the aesthetics are up to Jin, and we only talk about the content?

Comment: I would be against using the images of famous people. Being a skeptic is about thinking for yourself instead of following an authority.

Comment: @Borror0 Area 51 has aliens, why can't we? :D

Answer (score 1):

I always thought [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) would be quite a good fit :))

Comment: Area51 is my least favorite Stack Exchange site. It's too childish. It's hard to claim credibility when you've got tiny aliens pasted all over the place.

Comment: I think it's kinda cute, actually.

Answer (score 0):

As long as we don't use:

```
font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', Palatino, 'Hoefler Text', 'Book Antiqua', Georgia, serif;
```

Comment: Or Comic Sans MS!

Comment: Hmm, why not? Not saying that I’m for or against but these are bona fide, professional fonts and the declaration seems to cover all bases.